# Зазоры между таблицами в email-верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email

Добрый день! Делая email верстку столкнулся со следующей проблемой: после обнуления отступов таблиц, все равно остаются мелкие зазоры буквально в 1 а может в полпикселя. Обнуления безусловно делал строго по нескольким хабровским гайдам, вот краткий пример:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%">
```

Тем не менее на выходе получается следующее: 
[image: Еле заметная в браузерах, но все же очень бросающаяся в глаза на мобильных устройствах полоса]

[image: Мобильный gmail]

Эта полосочка - просвет заднего background-а. Можно конечно было этот самый background подогнать под соответствующий цвет, но проблема в том, что элемент-таблица, снизу и сверху которой образуются зазоры, находится между таблицами с разным фоном, то есть при любых изменениях фона таблицы или строки таблицы зазор появляется либо снизу либо сверху.

Откуда берется этот зазор в принципе, и можно ли как-то решить эту проблему? спасибо!

А вот сам код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; background: #8e344f;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
            <center style="max-width: 600px; min-width: 320px; width: 100%;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="30px"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%"> <!-- "width: 100%" / + "if gte mso 9" -->
                    <tr style="background: #512340;">
                        <td style="padding: 17px 0 0 0" align="center">
                            <span style="display: block; padding: 0 17px 15px 17px">
                                <img src="" width="137" height="46" alt="logo" border="0" style="display: block; padding: 0 0 15px 0; vertical-align: middle;"/>
                                <span style="display: block; color: #FDF6ED; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; vertical-align: middle;">Проверка</span>
                            </span>
                            <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/bottom_header.jpg" height="26" width="100%" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;"/> <!-- "width: 100%" -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; background: #fdf6ed;" width="100%"> <!-- "width: 100%" / + "if gte mso 9" -->
                    <tr style="background: #fdf6ed;">
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 25px 20px;">
                            <span style="display: block; color: #545450; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26.5px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 1px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Приветствуем Вас</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #fdf6ed;">
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 5px 20px 30px 20px;">
                            <span style="display: block; color: #545450; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 1px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Ваши учетные данные для входа:</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #fdf6ed;">
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 0 20px;">
                            <center style="max-width: 370px; width: 100%; background: #fff;"><!-- "width: 100%" -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #fdf6ed" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="50" width="130" style="background: #8e344f; -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -ms-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="40" height="17" valign="middle" align="center">
                                                        <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/login_icon.png" height="17" width="12" alt="" border="0"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left">
                                                        <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 0 10px 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Логин</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="15" style="background: #fff;"></td>
                                        <td style="background: #fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -ms-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -o-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;">
                                            <span style="display: block; padding: 0 5px 0 0; color: #545450; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: #545450; cursor: text;"></a></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="20" style="background: #fdf6ed;"></td>
                                        <td height="20" style="background: #fdf6ed;"></td>
                                        <td height="20" style="background: #fdf6ed;"></td>
                                        <td height="20" style="background: #fdf6ed;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="50" width="130" style="background: #8e344f; -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -ms-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%" >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="40" valign="middle" align="center">
                                                        <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/pass_icon.png" height="19" width="14" alt="" border="0"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 0 10px 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Пароль</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="15" style="background: #fff;"></td>
                                        <td style="background: #fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -ms-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; -o-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;">
                                            <span style="display: block; padding: 0 5px 0 0; color: #545450; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;"></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="100%"> <!-- "width: 100%" / + "if gte mso 9" -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="52" valign="bottom" style="background: #fdf6ed; border-bottom: solid 2px #5b063d;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; background: #8e344f;" width="100%"> <!-- "width: 100%" / + "if gte mso 9" -->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 40px 15px 10px 15px; background: #8e344f; border-bottom: solid #9f4662 1px;" align="center">
                            <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; vertical-align: top;">
                                <span style="display: inline-block; width: 135px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/dollar_1.png" height="47" width="54" alt="" border="0"/>
                                    <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Проверка <br>проверка</span>
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: inline-block; width: 135px;">
                                    <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/mail_1.png" height="47" width="66" alt="" border="0"/>
                                    <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Проверка <br>проверка</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px;">
                                <span style="display: inline-block; width: 135px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/card_1.png" height="47" width="49" alt="" border="0"/>
                                    <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Проверка <br>проверка</span>
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: inline-block; width: 135px;">
                                    <img src="http://aligoods.info/img/search_1.png" height="47" width="47" alt="" border="0"/>
                                    <span style="display: block; color: #fff; padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Проверка <br>проверка</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #8e344f; padding: 20px 0;" align="center">
                            <span style="display: block; color: #a95a73; padding: 0 0 5px 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Администрация <a href="alibonus.com" target="_blank" style="color: #a95a73; text-decoration: none;"> ... </a></span>
                            <span style="display: block; color: #a95a73; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .5px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">Подпись, контактные данные</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: какой зазор, по бокам пурпурный цвет?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, нет, сразу под оранжевой дугой. Обновляю вопрос, добавлю вид с мобильного клиента.

Comment: весь код сюда, у таблицы кстати одни border, у ячеек другие, задаются отдельно.

Comment: @Jean-Claude код прикрепил) но ведь ячейки таблицы не обнуляются...

Comment: а чо за браузер, в хроме/фоксе норм.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, бразуеры аналогичные, но  Вы попробуйте отправить себе на почту и через моб клиент открыть) Если не трудно конечно! Спасибо!